# maximum sum in IPL matches

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

In IPL 2025, the amount that each player is paid varies from match to match. The match fee depends on the quality of opposition, the venue etc.
The match fees for each match in the new season have been announced in advance. Each team has to enforce a mandatory rotation policy so that no player ever plays three matches in a row during the season.
Nikhil is the captain and chooses the team for each match. He wants to allocate a playing schedule for himself to maximize his earnings through match fees during the season.

```
Input: 10 3 5 7 3
Output: 23
(Explanation: 10+3+7+3)
Input: 3 2 3 2 3 5 1 3
Output: 17
(Explanation: 3+3+3+5+3)
```

My recurrence relation for this is as below which i want to know if it is right or wrong:

```
dp[i, 1] = max(dp[i-1][0] + c[i], dp[i-1][1])

dp[i, 0] = dp[i-1][1] + dp[i-2][1]
```

where dp[i, 1] means the maximum fees that can be get when playing 'i' match in the input array.

and dp[i, 0] means the maximum fees that can be get when not playing 'i' match in the input array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first simple idea is find the array `dp[N][3]`. Recurrence relation for:

```
dp[i][0] = max( dp[i-2][2] ,dp[i-2][1] )
dp[i][1] = max( dp[i-1][0] + A[i], dp[i-2][1] + A[i], dp[i-2][2] + A[i])
dp[i][2] = dp[i-1][1] + A[i]
```

The code for your problem bwlow

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include<cstring>
#include <math.h>
#include<cstdio>
#include<string>
#include <queue>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int dp[100000][3];
int main(){
    int n = 8;
    int A[] ={3,2,3,2,3,5,1,3};
    memset(dp,0,sizeof(dp));
    dp[0][1] = A[0];
    dp[1][1] = max(A[0],A[1]);
    dp[0][2] = A[0];
    dp[1][2] = A[0]+A[1];
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i = 2; i<n; i++){
        dp[i][0] = max(dp[i-2][2],dp[i-2][1]);
        dp[i][1] = max(max(dp[i-1][0]+A[i],dp[i-2][1]+A[i]),dp[i-2][2]+A[i]);
        dp[i][2] = dp[i-1][1]+A[i];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            ans = max(ans,dp[i][j]);
        }
    }
    cout<<ans;
    return 0;
}
```

If you think a little you will be able to optimaze the code.

Comment: At any match we have three choices:
1. This match we choose to not play (dp[i][0]) so we have to take max of previous matches max(dp[i-2][2],dp[i-2][1]);
2. This match is start of the sequence i.e. as we know we can only play two matches so this match is the first match in the sequence.
dp[i-1][0] + a[i] means we didn't chose previous match as the current match is the start of the sequence or we chose maximum from previous matches.
3. This match is the second match in the sequence. So we don't have any choice but to add the previous match points.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is wrong, in case `dp[i, 1]` , you didn't take into account the case when the player played in game `i - 1` and skip game `i - 2`, which is a valid case.

For case when you skip `ith` match, `dp[i, 0] = dp[i - 1][1] + dp[i - 2][1]` is also wrong, as `dp[i, 1]` takes into consider all matches from 0 to i, not just one matched, so adding both `dp[i - 1, 1]` and `dp[i - 1, 2]` will duplicate the calculation.

Fix:

```
dp[i, 1] = max(dp[i - 1, 0] + c[i]  , dp[i - 2, 0] + c[i - 1] + c[i])
dp[i, 0] = max(dp[i - 1, 1] , dp[i - 1, 0])
```

Comment: did you run it against the given set of input? I don't think this is correct as dp[i-1][0] + c[i] is for the case when previous was not selected and dp[i-1][1] is the case when previous is selected.

Comment: @newbie_old both of your formula is wrong, see my update

Comment: @newbie_old btw, can you give me the link to the problem statement? I cannot find IPL2025 on Google.

Comment: I will be wait for others to reply and see before delving into your solution.

Comment: @newbie_old take your time, I will try to improve it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73734/discussion-between-newbie-old-and-pham-trung).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily go on this problem with 1-D DP
Let:
dp[i] = sum  taking no 3 Consecutive elements till Index i .

Starting with base cases:

```
//taking only first element 
dp[0] = a[0];
//taking first and second element
dp[1] = a[1];
```

For third element we will have 3 cases :

1- Discarding 3rd element

```
dp[2] = d[1];
```

2- Discarding 2nd element :

```
dp[2] = dp[0] + a[2]
```

3- Discarding 1st element :

```
dp[2] = a[1] + a[2]
```

so Final Dp[2] will be maximum of these 3:

```
dp[2] = max( dp[1] , max( dp[0] + a[2] , a[1] + a[2] ) );
```

We can extend same approach for ith element :

```
  dp[i] = dp[i-1];
  dp[i] = max(dp[i],dp[i-2]+a[i]);
  dp[i] = max(dp[i],dp[i-3] + a[i-1]+a[i]);
```